# Herkunft des Spruchs "Anarchie ist machbar, Herr Nachbar!"

Tags: quotes

Heute morgen las ich den auf auf eine Brücke gesprayten Spruch:

> *Anarchie ist machbar, Herr Nachbar!*

Ist das ein Zitat, oder war da jemand kreativ?

Comment: Hmm, inwiefern sind die Resultate einer Internetsuche unzufriedenstellend?

Comment: Man kann einen Text finden, aber nicht den Urheber.

Comment: Dann solltest Du in Deiner Frage klarstellen, dass Du nach dem Urheber suchst und grob darlegen, was für eine Antwort Du erwartest bzw. wie weit Du selbst bei dieser Suche gekommen bist.

Comment: Bin mir nicht sicher, ob die Suche nach einem Urheber off-topic ist. Es ist zumindest grenzwertig.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solche Fragen beantwortet man am besten mit einer Google-Büchersuche sortiert nach Datum. Die ältesten Treffer geben meistens wertvolle Hinweise. In diesem Fall findet man für "ist machbar, Herr Nachbar" auch unter den frühesten Treffern in den Achtzigern die Variante mit Anarchie, aber eben auch folgende machbare Dinge:

- alles
- manches
- auch das
- Umweltschutz
- Frieden.

Im Web hab ich dann noch viel mehr für den Nachbar machbare Dinge gefunden, darunter Sozialismus, Gewerkschaft und Atomkrieg.

Soweit ich mich an diese Zeit erinnere, ist mir dieser Ausdruck *nicht* zum ersten Mal in Verbindung mit Anarchie begegnet. Ich habe diese Variante eigentlich immer als sarkastische Übernahme eines Spruchs vom entgegengesetzten politischen Spektrum aufgefasst. Das folgende Satzfragment aus einem Buch von 1985 (den ganzen Satz zeigt Google nicht an) scheint das zu bestätigen:

> [...], umfasst die Abkehr von der Machbarkeits-Ideologie ("Alles ist machbar, Herr Nachbar!") in den Siebzigern, umfasst [...]

Das klingt so, als würde dieser Satz die Machbarkeitsideologie der Siebzigerjahre repräsentieren. Ich vermute, der Satz wurde ursprünglich in den Sechzigern (Wirtschaftswunder) oder nicht viel später durch einen Film oder einen Werbespot populär. Er lässt sich natürlich sehr schön und einfach für alles Mögliche anpassen.

Im Spiegel-Archiv kommt das Motiv 1981 erstmals in der Anarchie-Variante vor (im Zusammenhang mit Hausbesetzern), und dann erneut 1982 in der alles-Variante als Gegensatz zu "endzeitlichen Versionen" (in einer Episode der "Stimmungslage"-Serie "Die deutsche Depression").

Möglicherweise auch relevant in diesem Zusammenhang ist der Titel einer 1991 erschienenen Ausgabe von Dutschke-Texten: [Geschichte ist machbar.](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_gefl%C3%BCgelter_Worte/G#Geschichte_ist_machbar.)

Gerade, als ich dachte, ich hab alles gefunden, bin ich über folgenden Eintrag im Buch "Die schönsten Zitate der Politiker" gestoßen:

> **Anarchie ist machbar, Herr Nachbar.**
>   Sogenannter Spontispruch aus den 70er Jahren, der einen Leitsatz der Studentenbewegung der 60er Jahre aufgriff: "Geschichte ist machbar".

Das widerspricht zum Teil dem, was ich oben geschrieben habe. Da ich aber die Qualität dieses Buchs nicht einschätzen kann und die Art, wie der Spruch damals auf die jüngeren Menschen gewirkt hat, ja ebenfalls relevant ist, lasse ich das jetzt einfach mal alles so stehen. Es ist aber auf jeden Fall eine plausible Erklärung, weil "Geschichte ist machbar" für sich bereits ein schönes Wortspiel ist und es nahe liegt, dass das später durch den Reim auf *Nachbar* noch weiter ironisiert wurde.

Comment: Vielen Dank für diese schöne Antwort! Die ist wirklich interessant. _Spontispruch_ war übrigens das erste, was mir durch den Kopf ging, als ich den Satz heute an der Brücke sah.

Answer (score 0):

**Ist das ein Zitat?**

Ja, das ist ein Zitat. Du selbst hast diesen Satz zitiert, also ist das ein Zitat.

**War da jemand kreativ?**

Ja, selbstverständlich. »Kreativ« kommt von »creare«, das ist lateinisch und bedeutet »erschaffen«. Es gab mal eine Zeit, da gab es dieses Satz noch nicht. Jetzt gibt es ihm. Also wurde er irgendwann zwischen diesen beiden Zeitpunkten erschaffen (er wurde kreiert). Und die Person, die das bewerkstelligt hat, war - per Definition - kreativ.

Achja (Ergebnis von 5 Sekunden googeln): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCIiVWecrFs

Mit ein bisschen mehr googeln findet man auch alle Informationen zur Band:

Die Rechte an dem Song, dessen Titel, Refrain und erste Zeile der zitierte Satz »Anarchie ist machbar, Herr Nachbar« ist, liegen bei der deutschen Punk-Band *Nevermind*. Dahinter steht Thorsten Dietrich aus Forsthausstr. 52, 36110 Schlitz. Auf http://www.nevermind-punk.de stehen sogar seine Telefonnummer und seine E-Mail-Adresse. Außer Thorsten Dietrich (Schlagzeug, Stimme und Kontaktperson) gehören noch Matthias Wachter (Stimme und Gitarre) und Petra Wanke (Bass und Stimme) zur Band.

Zu finden ist  der Song »Anarchie ist machbar, Herr Nachbar« übrigens auf der vor 15 Jahren (im Jahr 2000) im Eigenvertrieb erschienenen CD »Bier für die Musik«, die ab 2004 von Jag-M und danach vom Label NIX GUT vertrieben wurde.

Den Songtext kann man [hier](http://www.nevermind-punk.de/Lyrics/BfdM/anarchieismachbar.htm) und [hier](http://www.songtextemania.com/anarchie_ist_machbar_songtext_nevermind.html) und [hier](http://www.golyr.de/nevermind/songtext-anarchie-ist-machbar-259383.html) (und sicherlich noch an 20 anderen Stellen) nachlesen.

Comment: Hehe, du triffst den Nagel einer schlechten Frage wunderbar auf den Kopf ;)

Comment: Das muss mir jetzt bitte jemand erklären: Ich habe die beiden explizit gestellten Fragen korrekt und - wie ich meine - nachvollziehbar beantwortet, und habe auch die implizite Frage nach dem Urheber ausführlich beantwortet und mit Quellen belegt. Warum haben immerhin drei Leute diese Antwort trotzdem mit -1 bewertet? Dass die Frage schlecht war, sollte man ja wohl eher dem Fragesteller als dem Antwortgeber ankreiden. Auch dafür, dass der Songtext Müll ist, trage ich keine Verantwortung. Also bitte: Was genau ist an meiner Antwort so schlecht, das sie gleich dreimal runter gewertet wurde?

Comment: Wie ich gerade in einem Kommentar zu einer anderen Frage erwähnt habe, könnte es an der Art liegen, wie du die Frage beantwortet hast. Das ist nur meine Vermutung, ich kann nicht sagen, was jeder einzelne denkt. Ich habe den "korrekten" Teil übrigens nur überflogen und die Richtigkeit nicht hinterfragt, weil mich die Frage nicht interessiert. Nehmen wir an, es ist richtig. Was ich aber gelesen hatte, war deine Antwort vorm Edit und ich hatte das Gefühl, dass du den Fragesteller ziemlich blöd dastehen lassen wolltest. Eine Antwort war es bis dato nicht.

Comment: Ich hatte im zweiten Absatz aufgehört zu lesen, Du kannst Dir denken, warum. Ich habe jetzt auch den Rest gelesen und meine Stimme revidiert.